# Where condition in GQL query giving error

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, gqlquery

I am sorry if my query is stupid but please excuse me as i am new to google app engine and python 
I have and entity named Location

```
class Location(db.Model):
    place = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    address = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    approx_distance = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

The GQL query

```
location = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Location WHERE place='Mumbai'")
```

gives an attribute error

```
 AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'place'
```

Please help

Comment: In addition to the answer below, try using the model objects to perform queries.  `location = Location.all().filter('place = ','Mumbai').get()` rather than using GQL.  I have found 99% of the time I never use GQL.  Oh and if you are just starting out with appengine I would strongly suggest you use `ndb` rather than `db`.

Comment: The mistake that people often make is believing that GQL is somehow closer to the "native" datastore, in the same way that SQL is more native than an ORM in a traditional database. That's not the case: GQL is an artificial implementation on top of the query engine, just as the db/ndb libraries are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the line of code that error is happening on; it's not the lines you post. You're probably doing something like `location.place` later on, but `location` is a GqlQuery, not the results of the query. You probably want:

```
location = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Location WHERE place='Mumbai'").get()
```

To get the first result, or use `fetch` to get a list of results.